# Border-Box Transparent Border

Tags: css, transparent, border-box

I am trying to use border-box to create the effect of having a black 50% transparency border around 3 column images. I have read that in order to make the border move inwards to use padding and I cannot get it to work.

Here is my CSS code:

```
div.column-image {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 5px;
float: left;
}
```

And this is the result

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9dopCX5.jpg?1]

What I want is for the border to go inwards which will make the picture see through the border.

Here's an example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ib6YUVZ.jpg]

---

I have tried to follow the examples from this tutorial: [CSS Tricks: Transparent Borders with background-clip](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/), and have failed.

Please help I don't know what to do ~

Edit: Here's the live version of the [site](http://dev.baliliciousrestaurant.com/)

Comment: I think you want to put this CSS on the div, then put the image inside the div. You don't want to apply this to the image itself.

Comment: I second that motion... Look up "masking" in regards to CSS and HTML, you should be able to achieve the effect you want with that.

Answer (score 3):

Would you be open to doing this through a background-image and box-shadow solution? It's better practice to keep it minimal and cut down on unnecessary markup (both in your CSS and HTML). All you need is one div that will contain both the border and image.

```
.transparent-bordered-image {
    background-image: url(http://your-url-here);
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

This is an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fBY9z/1/

Answer (score 2):

Like this? [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/ePtp5/)

I added the border via a pseudo element placed on a wrapping `div` element.

Sadly, you can't use the psuedo element on the `img` itself, as the spec states:

> **12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements** [**(reference)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)
>
> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

**HTML**

```
<div id="imgwrap">
    <img/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#imgwrap {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#imgwrap:after {
    content:"\A";
    border:20px solid rgba(10, 0, 255, 0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -wekbit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
img { vertical-align:top; }
```